# Getting Street Name using jquery, ajax, json and google maps

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-maps

I am trying to get the name of the street from a set of co-ordinates. I can paste a URL like the one below into my browser to get data in JSON format.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=36.061637909151614,14.215711886063218&sensor=false

However, I am getting stuck when it comes to storing the returned data in a variable and then extract the value for the particular parameter I am interested in, in this case results/address_components/long_name.

I found samples to read code from a page into an element, and I found code to parse JSON, but I cannot figure out how to put them all together to get my final result, which is a string containing the Street Name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can I at least know why this question was down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Z6yhm/)

```
var longName;
$.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=36.061637909151614,14.215711886063218&sensor=false',function(data){
    longName = data.results[0].address_components[0].long_name;
});

$('button').on('click',function(){
    alert(longName);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) method:

```
var url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=36.061637909151614,14.215711886063218&sensor=false";

$.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    //console.log("JSON Data: " + json.results);
    $.each(json.results, function (index, value) {
        $.each(value.address_components, function (index, value) {
            console.log(index + ': ' + value.long_name);
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/zaT2F/)

Comment: Both answers are good but I could only choose one answer. Thanks though!